# Javascript window.open(..) fails due to "restrictions in effect on this computer"

Tags: javascript, policy, restrictions

A javascript call to `window.open(...)` fails for a particular user (but not for Administrator users)

The error message is `This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."`

The account is a domain account, but I am not able to find any differences between the failing domain account and the administrator domain account in the Active Directory Group Policy settings on the domain controller.

Google pointed me towards some posts which talks about the `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` registry hive but this hive doesn't even seem to be defined on the machine I'm diagnosing.

I've tried toggling/lowering some popup-blocker setting without any positive results.

Any good suggestion about what I may be missing?

EDIT: window.ShowModelessDialog(..) seems to work without errors while window.Open(..) doesn't. It would still be preferable for to use window.open(..) so I'd like to find a different way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the setting in the internet options ---> Security tab search for "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bar".

this would help

Comment: No, I added the question when I was on a client visit, and it will probably take a little time before I can get back to that client. I gave you a +1 on a different answer through :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue.  In our case it was due to the following group policy being enforced:

User configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Browser Menus/Disable Open in New Window menu option

I know it seems strange that this policy would interfere with javascript pop-ups, (it's only meant to disable the Open in New Window menu option in IE's context menu) but it does.
Fortunately in our case we were also using the Disable Context Menu policy, so we could reset the above mentioned policy to Not Configured (and thus be able to access pop-ups) without reducing our security.